# Build errors require restart of Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, build-error

We are are developing a C#-Application with Visual Studio 2010 and Team Foundation Server 2010 using Windows 7 64-Bit as OS.

It happens pretty often that build errors occur when locally compiling. These errors are gone after restarting Visual Studio.

I recognized that this is especially the case when bigger changes in the code base are checked out from TFS. Cleaning the solution does not help.

This looks like a very strange behavior of Visual Studio. Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: It might help if you expand on *what kind* of build errors. I hardly believe that a restart of Visual Studio is going to fix something like missing semi colons and the like. =)